# Set scaling property to fit to in Excel using C# with OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, export-to-excel

I've made a asp.net page that creates an Excel workbook. I have set the orientation scaling property of the page setup height and width of the workbook like so:

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PageSetup pgOr = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PageSetup();
    pgOr.Orientation = OrientationValues.Landscape;
    pgOr.FitToHeight = 3;
    pgOr.FitToWidth = 1;
    newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(pgOr);
```

However, when you download the Excel document and open the PageSetup scaling has been set to 1 page wide and 3 pages tall which is what I want but the "Fit to" radio button isn't selected so it's not actually using these setting.

I figured there is some property I need to set to true along the way. Like a FitToPage or something the thing is that I don't know which one. Anyone know?

**NOTE: Please keep in mind that I am using DocumentFormat.OpenXml and not Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OpenXML SDK provides a class called `PageSetupProperties` which provides a property called `FitToPage`.
Set this property to `true` in order to get the radio button selected:

```
SheetProperties sp = new SheetProperties(new PageSetupProperties());

Worksheet ws = newWorksheetPart.Worksheet;
ws.SheetProperties = sp;

// Set the FitToPage property to true
ws.SheetProperties.PageSetupProperties.FitToPage = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true);

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PageSetup pgOr = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.PageSetup();
pgOr.Orientation = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.OrientationValues.Landscape;
pgOr.FitToHeight = 3;
pgOr.FitToWidth = 1;
ws.AppendChild(pgOr);
```

Answer (score 0):

must be set FitToPage, xml code see bellow:

```
sheet1.xml
...
<sheetPr>
    <pageSetUpPr fitToPage="1"/>
</sheetPr>
...
```